# root folder's url

Tags: google-apps-script

The `DocsList.getRootFolder().getUrl()` produces url which leads to such content for me:

```
Sorry, the page (or document) you have requested does not exist.

Make sure that you have the correct URL and that the owner of the document hasn't deleted it.
```

Is it bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Drive UI, the folders that return a valid URL also seem to have the drill-down option for 'Share...', which produces a URL that can be accessed by those with permissions. Since the root folder does not have such a drill-down option, I can understand why the URL Apps Script provides leads to such a message. Perhaps this behavior should be documented better -- feel free to open an issue on the [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) to address this in the documentation.

Comment: to be clear. so i can never get the valid url for root folder?